# Type mismatch error in recursive function in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

I have the following recursive call written in Scala:

```
  def calculateFingerPrint(t: Tree):Int =
{
  if(t.isInstanceOf[Leaf])
    calculateIDS(t).hashCode()

  else if(t.isInstanceOf[OtherNode])
    //error --> calculateIDS(t).concat(calculateFingerPrint(t.children.head).toString()).hashCode 

}

 def calculateIDS(t: Tree):String= {
//returns some string
}
```

The commented line is throwing type mismatch error and saying `Found: Anyval Required:Int`.

Can anyone please tell what is the problem here?

Comment: Could you please share all the code necessary to reproduce the problem? - BTW, you should not call `isInstanceOf` in **Scala**, we have better tools like **pattern matching** for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a final `else` clause to return the default value if `t` is not `Leaf` or `OtherNode`.

A `match` expression would be better than using `isInstanceOf` calls.

Comment: So, scala will throw error if there is no final else statement unlike Java where you could write this same code without specifying a final `else`.

Comment: It will not throw an error, the problem is type of `if` without `else` is `Unit` (type of `if` with `else` is a common super-type of both possible results).